# How to get the name of the calling class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

So [inspect.stack()[1].function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack) gives the name of the calling function, which is nice. However, for methods in classes, this just gives the plain name of the method.

How can I get the name of the class of the calling method?

The only way I found so far was using [sys._getframe()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe):

```py
caller = sys._getframe(1).f_locals["self"]
class_name = caller.__class__.__name__
```

However, this seems to be rather risky because of the "_" prefix in the name and the following warning in the documentation:

> This function should be used for internal and specialized purposes only. It is not guaranteed to exist in all implementations of Python.

Is there a cleaner way to do this, in particular using `inspect`?

For reference here is a simplified but complete example for an Django application with a lot of views that are pretty similar, but still different depending on a few parameters. In particular, they issue several similar log messages. So I added a `ViewContext` that captures the similarities and handles the standardized log messages. Initially setting it up required the `View` to create a `Logger` and pass it to the `ViewContext`:

```py
class SomeView:
    def some_method(self):
        self._logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)  # cumbersome
        view_context = ViewContext(self._logger)  # cumbersome
        view_context.info("doing something")
```

Now with `sys._getframe()` the `ViewContext` can find the logger by itself:

```py
class ViewContext:
    def __init__(self):
        caller = sys._getframe(1).f_locals["self"]
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(caller.__class__.__name__)

    def info(self, message):
        self.logger.info(message)
```

This simplifies the `View` to:

```py
class SomeView:
    def some_method(self):
        view_context = ViewContext()
        view_context.info("doing something")
```

It works, but I'm still concerned about `sys._getframe()` being too kinky to put it into robust code.

Comment: `inspect.stack` should be treated as having the same warning attached as `sys._getframe`. Both of them poke at stack frame implementation details that aren't guaranteed to exist on all implementations.

Comment: Also, your code is doing a lot of things different from what you seem to think it's doing. For example, `caller.__class__` is the wrong class, and `caller.__class__.__name__` would be a different name from the `__name__` in your original code even if `caller.__class__` was the right class.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica True, the logger names got messed up when trying to extract the relevant parts from my actual code. They should be consistent now.